# Call to undefined Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::detach()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo el problema de que intento desasociar algunos elementos de una tabla, la tabla supervisor es la tabla padre y la de operador es la tabla hija, pero me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la relación en el modelo de supervisor:

```
// un supervisor puede tener muchos operadores
public function operadores(){
    return $this->hasMany(Operador::class);
}
```

Esta es la relacion en mi modelo Operador:

```
public function supervisor(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Este es el método en mi controlador:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $supervisor = Supervisor::findOrFail($id);
    $supervisor->update($request->all());
    $supervisor->operadores()->detach($request->operadores);
    return redirect()->route('supervisores.index', $supervisor)->with('success', 'El supervisor fue actualizado con éxito!');
}
```

Ya que existe la relación uno a muchos (un supervisor tiene muchos operadores), me gustaría poder quitarle algunos operadores a un supervisor y viceversa.

En dado caso que este mal empleado el método, he utilizado todos los que deja disponible Eloquent en su [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method).

Comment: Estás empleando el método de forma incorrecta, `detach` solo existe en relaciones de *Muchos a muchos* es decir en Eloquent será: `belongsToMany`

Comment: Por favor explica mejor lo que deseas hacer posterior a la actualización para poder ofrecer una respuesta

Comment: Ya la modifique, espero que ahora me entiendas mejor.

Comment: Ok, pero ¿qué quieres que ocurra una eliminación permanente cuando le quite operadores a un supervvisor o simplemente que se actualicen y queden con un status de 0 o algo así?

Comment: Que se actualicen con un status nulo o cero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Considera que estás intentado usar el método [`dettach`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) el cual existe en el *trait* **`InteractsWithPivotTable`**, este trait es usado en la clase **`BelongsToMany`** ubicada en: **`..../Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php`** de ahi que te indique en el mensaje de error *que el método no esta definido en la clase `HasMany`*

Si lo que buscas es que los registros asociados a algún modelo en específico se actualicen, lo que debes hacer es:

1. Busca por id el modelo de `Supervisor` y asignalo a una variable
2. Posterior harás una *actualización masiva* donde la condición para los modelos de `Operadores` será donde el id del supervisor registrado como llave foránea sea igual al recuperado en el paso 1.

Propuesta de código:

```
$idSupervidor = Supervisor::findOrFail($id);

Operador::where('llave_foranea', $idSupervisor)
        ->update(['status' => 0]);
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [actualización masiva](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates)
- [attaching y detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

Comment: Muchas gracias, te agradezco tu respuesta. Me aclaro la mente.

Comment: no hay de que @GeniusDesign :)